# React-router 1.0.3 nested routes children empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am following the example here

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps

I ported the code over to my stack, and it seems that all of the GlobalNav links work fine,  however when I goto some of the nested routes in Course,  this.props.children is undefined.

This is what I have so far converted the code to es6

```js
// MAIN entry for webpack

import React from 'react';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import stubbedCourses from './stubs/COURSES';

import App      from './components/App';
import Calendar from './routes/Calendar';
import Course   from './routes/Course';
import Grade    from './routes/Grades';
import Message  from './routes/Messages';
import Profile  from './routes/Profile';

var rootRoute = {
  component: 'div',
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
      Calendar,
      Course  ,
      Grade   ,
      Message ,
      Profile ,
    ]
  }]
};

render(
  <Router routes={rootRoute} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

```js
//Course/index.js

import Announcements from './routes/Announcements';
import Assignments   from './routes/Assignments';
import Grades        from './routes/Grades';
import Course        from './components/Course';


module.exports = {
  path: 'course/:courseId',

  getChildRoutes (location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, [
        Announcements,
        Assignments  ,
        Grades
      ])
    })
  },

  getComponent (location, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, Course)
    })
  }
};
```

```js
//Changed Course.js

import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import Nav from './Nav';

var styles = {};

styles.sidebar = {
  float: 'left',
  width: 200,
  padding: 20,
  borderRight: '1px solid #aaa',
  marginRight: 20
};

class Course extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let { children, params } = this.props;
    let course = COURSES[params.courseId];

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{course.name}</h2>
        <Nav course={course} />
      
        // Props not passed down
        {children && children.sidebar && children.main ? (
      
          <div>
            <div className="Sidebar" style={styles.sidebar}>
              {children.sidebar}
            </div>
            <div className="Main" style={{padding: 20}}>
              {children.main}
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Dashboard />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Course;
```

[image: My directory structure, identical to the example]

When I run them side by side in the debugger

[image: The original]

[image: This is mine]

Comment: I'm not seeing in your code where you even make use of `Courses`. In your root route definition, you define `Course` as a child route instead of `Courses`. Was that a typo?

Comment: Oh yes sorry that was a typo.  fixing it now

Comment: Oh yes sorry that was a typo.  fixing it now.  Also, **// Props not passed down** comment is where the issue is.  When I pull the actual demo and  run it locally,  and place a debugger at the same spot.  I see the data being passed down

Comment: Hm. I'm still a little confused. Where is says "Props not passed down", what are the props that should be there that aren't? And to where are they not propagated?

Comment: When I run the demo and my code side by side with the debugger at the same spot,  I added a few more pictures